# Handle POST request from multiple routes all at once

Tags: node.js, forms, express, routes

I am submitting a simple contact form in my website's footer (in `footer.pug`):

```
form(method="POST" action="contact_form")
  input(type='email' name='ct_email' data-name='ct_email' required)
  textarea(type='text' name='ct_message' data-name='ct_message' required)
  button(type='submit') Send
```

Since the form is in a template, and the footer template is used throughout the site, the form can be submitted from various routes:

- `/contact_form`
- `/route1/contact_form`
- `/route1/de/contact_form`
- and so on...

So now it seems I have to create a handler for all the possible routes:

```
router.post('/contact_form', function(req, res, next) {
  // ...
}

router.post('/route1/contact_form', function(req, res, next) {
  // ...
}
```

How can I easily handle POST requests from all the routes they may be coming from **without writing a handler for each**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute path reference in your form and it will always submit to the same route even though the form is in different pages.

Try this

```
form(method="POST" action="/contact_form")
```

Notice the action changed from `contact_form` to `/contact_form`. When you add `/`, you start referencing the path as an absolute path to the domain. So now, from all pages, the form will be submitted to `http://your-domain/contact-form`.

Comment: Ah yes! The absolute path is what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if this is what you mean, but the first argument to ExpressJS's router (I assume that's what `router` is doing here) *can* be an array. So instead of:

```
router.post('/contact_form', function(req, res, next) {
    // ...
}

router.post('/route1/contact_form', function(req, res, next) {
    // ...
}
```

You can just do:

```
router.post(['/contact_form','route1/contact_form'],function(req,res,next){
    //some fancy logic to handle both routes.
})
```

Of course, this requires that you keep a list of these possible routes. On the other hand, you can follow Dinesh Pandiyan's advice, and just use an absolute path. So instead of page1.html, page2.html, page3.html, etc. all having their own own router (or own entry in your router array), you'd essentially be saying "Go to the domain route, then go to this address".

Answer (score 0):

Each request should be handled in separated functions because each request has its own logic. However if you want

```
function request(req, res, next) {
// Your logic
}

router.post('/contact_form', request) {
  // ...
}

router.post('/route1/contact_form', request) {
  // ...
}
```

Right now, I don't have a way to test this code, but I think that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another potential solution - use an independent function as a route handler.

```
router.post('/a', handlePost);
router.post('/b', handlePost);
router.post('/c', handlePost);

function handlePost(req, res, next){
  // use req.path here to figure out what url was called 

}
```